# Wake On Lan through RPI 1b+ v1.2

Tags: networking, ssh, ethernet, remote, raspberry-pi-os

Could you guys help me out with setting up a WOL setting? There's a catch. I've googled a bit and found solutions but I want something more delicate. Google suggests that I remotely execute a bash script waking the target computer. I want to make it simpler. For example, by sending magic packet to the Pi computer (which is already running, of course) which will be used as an event trigger to wake another PC. Is it possible to achieve?

I am running a Raspbery Pi OS June 2021.

Comment: okay, I've managed to wake up the target PC with this command:

socat -u udp-recvfrom:10,fork exec:scripts/pi-wol.sh

I figured it out a little. The package loop happens when I sent a magic packet to the broadcast address which is 192.168.1.255. If I send it straight to the target pc IP, it works perfectly. Now, I tried adding this line to end of the /etc/rc.local, but it doesn't seem to work at startup. How do I make it so socat starts listening for packets at startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after some days of struggle and figuring this stuff out, I've finally made it happen. What I did was:

1. wrote a bash script that sends a magic packet with the mac address of the target pc to the local IP-address with a port of that pc.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo wakeonlan -i 12.121.12.12 -p 99 1a:2b:3c:4d:5e:6f
```

2. installed socat
3. figured out the command which I need to make it listen constantly for the packet on the specified port: `sudo socat -u udp-recvfrom:10,fork exec:scripts/pi-wol.sh`
4. added it as a systemd service by using this [guide](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/start-service-at-boot/). Had to move the script to /usr/bin, so it could be started at startup by root. Eventually the service file looked like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Socat WOL

[Service]
Type=simple
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=socat-wol

ExecStart=/usr/bin/socat -u udp-recvfrom:10,fork exec:/usr/bin/pi-wol.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What happens now is when I send a magic packet to my RPi through internet (don't forget to port forward sent packets to your local Pi) RPi recieves it and the script is triggered - it sends a wol-packet to my target pc waking it up from turned off state.

I spent 4 days of constant googling and getting on people's nerves to get here and now I see it all could be done in 4 simple steps which take 15 minutes or less.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `tcpdump` or `wireshark` to monitor the network interface on the Pi and set up a filter for the magic packet of your choice. For example, for a ping packet that could be:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 icmp and icmp[icmptype]=icmp-echo
```

Pipe the output of `tcpdump` to a script which wakes up the target computer on any new input:

```
while read line; do wakeonlan <mac address>; done
```

and the target computer should wake up every time someone pings your Pi.

Comment: I get the general idea of what you are trying to suggest but I am rather new to this whole linux and raspberry pi thing so making scripts is a little out of my league here. I would appreciate if you could elaborate on the second part a little.

Comment: @magrega Did you get a solution you mention in the question (with a bash script) running? Perhaps you should start with that, a tutorial will teach you how to write scripts and will be a useful test step for the final solution.

Comment: okay, I've managed to wake up the target PC with this command:

socat -u udp-recvfrom:10,fork exec:scripts/pi-wol.sh

I figured it out a little. The package loop happens when I sent a magic packet to the broadcast address which is 192.168.1.255. If I send it straight to the target pc IP, it works perfectly. Now, I tried adding this line to end of the /etc/rc.local, but it doesn't seem to work at startup. How do I make it so socat starts listening for packets at startup?

Comment: @magrega Make it a systemd service instead of rc.local. Then you'll be able to schedule it after the networking service.

Comment: How do I make it startup with the system without me logging in?